# Redux-persist keeps on loading

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

#### Motivation

I'd like to keep user information on page refresh/redirect, but also I want to clear it after logout action.

---

#### Configuration

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({productsReducer, auth: accessReducer, usersReducer});

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['auth']
};
```

I want to persist data only in `accessReducer` that's why it's whitelisted. Now I want to handle logout in such way that all data in reset. To do so I've created logoutReducer:

#### Logout reducer

```js
export const logout = () => ({
    type: 'USER_LOGOUT'
});

const logoutReducer = (state, action) => {
    if(action.type = 'USER_LOGOUT'){
        state = undefined;
    }

    return rootReducer(state, action);
};
```

#### Store and persistor

```js
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, logoutReducer);
export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

---

### PROBLEM

Once I run the application, I get loading information which comes from a `<Loader/>` in `PersistGate`:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={<Loader/>} persistor={persistor}>
        ...
    </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

### POSSIBLE CAUSE

Now I guess it's because I pass `logoutReducer` which has only reference to other reducers and that's why configuration fails. How do I persist user information and keep that logout-clear-store trick? Is there any other solution for this? Any help would be appreciated ♥

Comment: You can maybe call `persistor.purge()`?

Comment: @David I've created async function in which I call `await persistor.purge()` and linked it with on click in my logout button, but once I click it - nothing happens. I mean the `store.getState()` remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ANSWER

During doing research about this problem I've found [this](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/770) issue, where poster had similar problem. Solution is in the last comment in this post, that is:
**[react-reset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-reset)**.
Here is my application of this package to mentioned above problem:

```js
const appReducer = combineReducers({productsReducer, auth: accessReducer, usersReducer});

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['auth']
};

const enHanceCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    reduxReset()
)(createStore);

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, appReducer);
export const store = enHanceCreateStore(persistedReducer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Then you just simply on logout dispatch action given from `redux-reset`:

```js
store.dispatch({
  type: 'RESET'
})
```